# different servers different databases replication mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication, mysql5, mysql5.5, mysql-cluster

I am not sure if this is possible or not but I have 3 servers.

```
Server A, B and C
Server A has database A_dataBase, B_database
Server B has database A_dataBase, B_database and C_database
Server C has database C_database
```

Currently Server A and B are in sync perfectly.
Now I want to sync the database C_database between server B and Server C.

Server B has this my.cnf

```
###
server-id = 2
log_bin                = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
binlog_do_db           = A_dataBase
binlog-do-db           = B_database
relay-log = /var/log/mysql/slave-relay.log
relay-log-index = /var/log/mysql/slave-relay-log.index
#####
```

This is the command I ran on Server B to set server A up

```
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST = 'serverA_ip', MASTER_USER = 'username', MASTER_PASSWORD = 'userpassword', MASTER_LOG_FILE = 'mysql-bin.000007', MASTER_LOG_POS = 107;
```

Now my question is how to setup the sync of C_database between server C and B? Keeping in mind that I already have syncing working between A and B

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Multi-Source Replication enables a replication slave to receive transactions from multiple sources simultaneously. It is supported by Mysql 5.7.6 or later.
Here there is the documentation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-multi-source.html
https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/10/02/mysql-5-7-multi-source-replication/